# handle if in a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a better way to accomplish this if condition using maybe `?` operator

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.valores))
        {
            @crearContenedorTipo(
                Model.IDTipodato,
                Model.minimo, Model.maximo,
                Model.valores.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
                Model.salida, Model.IDCampo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.Nombre)
        }
        else 
        { 
            @crearContenedorTipo(
                Model.IDTipodato,
                Model.minimo, Model.maximo,
                new string[] {},
                Model.salida, Model.IDCampo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.Nombre)
        }
```

here's the signature of my helper

```
@helper crearContenedorTipo(int tipoDato, int? min, int? max, string[] valor, bool salida, int id)
```

Comment: The best way would be to move the if out of the view and into the controller. Views should not contain logic.

Comment: If know, that views should not contain logic but i can't avoid it on this case

Comment: Why not have the controller do the split string before passing the model ?

Comment: because my helper function build an html different in diferent scenarios I to handle this scenarios I can't manipulate the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read your code, the `if` is only there to guard against a null or empty string. The rest of the block is the same, apart from the Model.valores argument. Therefore, this would be equivalent to your code:

```
@crearContenedorTipo(
                Model.IDTipodato,
                Model.minimo, Model.maximo,
                (Model.valores ?? String.Empty).Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
                Model.salida, Model.IDCampo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.Nombre)
```

This works because of StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries - when the string is empty, no items is returned.